# Routing error using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have a routing issue which I can't seem to get my head around.

I have a project resource which has all the restfull actions working as expected.

Now I want to add the ability to update one specific attribute through a small popup form. So in this popup I use:

```
form_tag (@project) do
  text_field_tag :attribute_i_want_to_update, ''
  submit_tag 'go'
```

In the controller's update action I intend to handle this specific submit. However I receive a routing error claiming there is no route to '/projects/15'. I checked that the request is using a POST. Obviously a route exists for a POST to '/projects/15' (e.g. the regular update route works fine and posts to that exact route).

What am I missing?

Thx for your time,
Erwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951029/rails-3-route-problem)

If the object is not new, then rails (at least 3 does this) will look for a PUT route, not POST. If you check what is really sent to the server, using Firebug for example, you will see that a POST is made but with a param "_method=put".

Rails will look for a PUT route to update an existing object, which is in accordance with Fielding's definition of REST.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying it as a PUT request:

```
form_tag(@project, :method => :put) do
  text_field_tag :attribute_i_want_to_update, ''
  submit_tag 'go'
```